# About inserting array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

After retrieving the values from a table using fetch function and putting it into `$row[variable]`.

Is there a way store those values into another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shure Simply use a "normal" INSERT Statement  and insert your Data to a new table

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('$row[name]', 'row[surname]','$row[age]')");
```

You might want to iterate with a foreach / while over your incomming rose

Or directly use the loop from retrieving the data to insert them again somewhere else

Comment: hmmm so just mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(FirstName) VALUES ('$row[variable]'))"; so just this? :o

Comment: tell me more of your code like your vars, and i can update the example

Comment: $qry1  = "SELECT id, flavor FROM flavor ORDER BY id"; 
$resultflav = mysql_query($qry1); 

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultflav)) 
{ 
 echo 
 
 "<table width=118 height=30 border=0>".
 "<tr>".
 "<td>$row1[flavor]</td>".
 "</tr>".
 "</table>";

this is the code the code wherein it shows the flavors from my table.. what I want is to enter them to another table

Comment: jep then you have $row['id'] and $row['flavor'] just adapt my insert state ment and integrate it to your while loop and you are done.

SO you have to change the Table Persons to ... , (Colums) to the columes you want and then values

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after the retrieving the value in $row[variable] you can run a simple insert query with the above variable like,

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("Insert into table (field_name1) values ("'.$row[variable].'")");
?>
```